# Pinchas didn't carry a spear?

Tags: sources-mekorot, parshanut-torah-comment, pinchas, chatam-sofer

In discussing Pinchas, the Chasam Sofer reportedly says that the kana'im who *don't* carry around a spear are the true kanai'm lishma while those who carry around a spear looking for a machlokes are not true kanai'm.

Where does the Chasam Sofer say this?

For more context, I heard that Pinchas wasn't carrying a spear looking for a fight, rather he needed to go take one:

> וַיַּרְא פִּינְחָס בֶּן־אֶלְעָזָר בֶּן־אַהֲרֹן הַכֹּהֵן וַיָּקָם
> מִתּוֹךְ הָעֵדָה **וַיִּקַּח רֹמַח בְּיָדוֹ**׃  When Pinchas, son of
> Elazar son of Aharon the kohen, saw this, he left the assembly and,
> **he took a spear** in his hand." ([Bamidbar 25:7](https://www.sefaria.org/Numbers.25.7?vhe=Tanach_with_Ta%27amei_Hamikra&lang=bi&aliyot=0))

Comment: Does the Chasam Sofer refer to a metaphorical spear?

Comment: See Sanhedrin 82a

Comment: Are you sure this is a Chassam Soffer? I'm pretty sure I've seen this in Emes LiYaakov from Reb Yaakov Kaminetzky.